# Fetching data from php file and using javascript to print selected data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

I have 2 divs in my html page. Using AJAX, JavaScript, I send my query parameters to a php file, which returns combined results for the 2 divs. I want to know how to separate the result in JavaScript and display in their respective divs.

```js
<script>
function fetchData() {
  var yr = document.getElementById('entry').value;
  if (yr.length==0) { 
    document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML="";
 return;
  }

  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
  {
  var content = xmlhttp.responseText;
 if (content == "%<searchword>%")
  document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = content;
 else  
  document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = content; 
     }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","db.php?q="+ yr ,true);
  xmlhttp.send(); 
}
</script>
```

```html
<body>

<form>
Enter year: <input type="text" id="entry" />
<input type="button" value="check here" onclick="fetchData()" />
</form>
<div id="result1">result 1 here</div>
<div id="result2"> result 2 here</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You are going to need to show us what you've done so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return json as PHP output, that is best for Javascript (do not forget json php headers, use json_encode), like this:

```
{
    "div1": "Content for div 1",
    "div2": "DIV 2 content"
}
```

Easy with jQuery [getJSON method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), or jQuery [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: urlToPHPFile,
    data: dataToSend,
    success: function( jsonResponse ) {
        $('#result1').html( jsonResponse.div1 );
        $('#result2').html( jsonResponse.div2 );
    }
});
```

To send request with pure Javascript take a look at [this article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/XMLHttpRequest).

To parse JSON just [read this article](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp).

So, with pure Javascript you get something like this:

```
function alertContents(httpRequest){
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4){
        // everything is good, the response is received
        if ((httpRequest.status == 200) || (httpRequest.status == 0)){
            var obj = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
            var div1 = getElementById('result1');
            var div2 = getElementById('result2');
            div1.innerHTML = obj.div1;
            div2.innerHTML = obj.div2;
        }else{
            alert('There was a problem with the request. ' + httpRequest.status + httpRequest.responseText);
        }
    }
};

function send_with_ajax( the_url ){
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { alertContents(httpRequest); };  
    httpRequest.open("GET", the_url, true);
    httpRequest.send(null);
};

function fetchData() {
    var yr = document.getElementById('entry').value;
    if (yr.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    send_with_ajax( "db.php?q=" + yr );
};

fetchData();
```

Comment: I do not wish to use jquery. I am trying to make changes in the javascript code, in order to do that. I have added code snippet of the javascript.

Comment: i want my results to be displayed separately in divs result1 and result2, after i search for a keyword in the javascript.

Comment: I updated the answer. Haven't tested it, but you have the hook now, wish you catch lot of fish.